# Using SBJson in a non-ARC project

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, sbjson

I am developing an IOS application, using the [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) library. I don’t use ARC on my project, and previous SBJson releases didn't use it, either.

But now SBJson uses ARC and I have to upgrade to the latest SBJson release. I viewed the SBJson classes and I saw this:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "This source file must be compiled with ARC enabled!"
#endif
```

How can I upgrade SBJson in my project?

Comment: Have you looked into the NSJSONSerialization ? It is built by apple and is super fast and very easy to work with and is available from iOS 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use compiler flags to enable and disable ARC for particular files in your project.

Please find more information in official notes [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW15)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark all files  with ARC enabled.

Here is a sample how to do that:

http://www.codeography.com/images/arc-compiler-flag.png